# What sugar to use when transferring to bottle or barrel

Tags: bottling, sugar, priming, barrels

Doing a homebrew for the first time, bought a kit to do it with; figured it be a good student method of saving money :).

Anyway, its currently in the fermenting bin, and when it comes to transferring I plan to transfer into a barrel rather than bottles.

One of the instructions is to add about 3oz of sugar per 5 gallons, but what kind of sugar would this be? Is it more brewing sugar, or can regular sugar or a different kind be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Almost anything, really, would work...

If you want gas in your beer, kind of sugar does not matter, anything that ferment will work.

## .. but every thing will work in it's own way

### Glucose

Will ferment clean, probably with hardly any side effects. Good choice, easy to obtain and pretty cheap.

### Dry wort extract

Take about 20% more than sugar. It will be most "authentic" because, well, wort should be the only fermentable in your beer unless you know exactly why you want something else.

### Regular table sugar

Works for me. Some say it brings wine-y tastes to your beer, but no one ever told me to taste them in my brew. But I tend to brew heavy ales. If you brew something more delicate, avoid table sugar. Better safe than sorry.

### Reserve

Pasteurizing part of wort before fermentation, keeping in the reserve and adding it back just before bottling works just like wort extract priming, only better. Literally no way it would ever introduce foreign tastes. This time is too late, but oh well. I never do it because it's a bit troublesome and benefit seems not worth it. But that's my personal opinion.

### Raw cane sugar

If you want your beer taste a bit like rum, that might be the way to go. I used it happily to enrich my dark beers.

### Molasses

Heavy change in taste. For really dark beers if, just before bottling, you decide this is exactly what they are lacking. use with caution and remember to take more of it than you would with sugar, but it will work, too.

### Honey

Most probably it will *not* bring any honey-like taste or aroma to your beer. Waste of money unless you do it for some other reason.

### "Priming tabs", "beer sugar", "brewing sugar" etc

Most of them are just one thing or mix of things I described above, with price doubled or tripled and fancy name on them. Would not buy. But if you already have stock of it, better use it for priming than main fermentation.

Comment: Thanks for that, highly appreciated.Will see if somewhere around me sells Glucose and get some of that. When you "Beer Sugar" etc, in the last part, do you mean brewing sugar? Or, should I stick to brewing sugar at the start of the process?

Comment: @ChrisBarsby Yes, i mean Brewing sugar there as well. It usually is a mix of dry wort extract, glucose and table sugar (sometimes only one or two of the three). If you can afford it, never use it for anything. Pure wort extract will bring much more taste to your beer. 1:1 should be fine replacement, and it is not that more expensive.

Comment: I use 1kg of brewing sugar this time, so 1kg of Wort Extract will be essentially the same? Then at bottling/barreling, 20% extra (3.6oz in this case) as opposed to a sugar of some sort?

Will have to try and find a UK supermarket that sells it and give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisBarsby 1kg of dry wort extract instead of 1kg sugar means about 0.5% ABV lower, and much more taste. Less watery. For priming, you need the same amount of fermentables to get the same amount of gas. For main brew, you do not need o cover lack of taste with higher alcohol content, so lower amount of fermentables does not hurt. But of course if ABV matters (like, if your kit is on the lower side of style already), use more wort extract. For me, taste is what dictates things, not ABV or styles ;)

Comment: I'd rather it tasted good than had a higher ABV. Will definitely be looking for Wort Extract though, thanks for the help. Hugely appreciated

Comment: @ChrisBarsby good  luck! and see my edit to my last comment, I put some last-minute clarification there.