# can I use granulated sugar in place of brewing sugar?

Tags: wine, fruit, sugar

I've got my first home brew kit for blackberry wine, can I use normal household granulated sugar instead of brewing sugar?

Comment: Useful information was already posted here about sugars: [What sugar to use...](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/16153/what-sugar-to-use-when-transferring-to-bottle-or-barrel)

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can.  I do it all the time and have done it dozens of times.  No problem at all.